# Passing domain model business entity to UI layer question

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, entity, viewmodel, mvp

Is that acceptable to pass directly domain model entity to UI layer instead of corresponding viewmodel?

In my example UI gets some user data and passes it down to presenter which interacts with domain service. Domain service performs some action on the data from the user and returns output results back to UI as domain model entity, which should be typically converted to viewmodel.

The problem is that depending on the user choice (Y or N) inspecting the returned result, it may be returned back to the service for further processing and finally saved to repository.

If we do not save returned domain entity somewhere between those 2 steps, but use viewmodel, we will not be able to pass it back for further processing.

Are there some workarounds when such user interaction takes place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MVP` is defined around the concept of `View`, `Presenter`, and `Model`. There's no reason you need to distinguish between a domain entity and a *view* `Model`. They can (and should) be the same thing.

Unlike `MVVM`, the model plays less of a role in binding to the `View`. It's the responsibly of the presenter to manipulate the view using the model data. There is no concept of a `ViewModel` as such in MVP. That term is generally reserved for `MVVM` where `ViewModel` is an entity tightly coupled to `View`, in addition to having a `Model`.

Comment: I'd say, view model rather than model view is more applicable term for MVVM due to the coupling of the view model to the view, ie, its more a "model of the view" than a "view of the model"

Comment: Sorry I meant ViewModel, as in `Model` `View` `ViewModel`.

Comment: ok, how do we proceed in the case of using ViewmMdels? I'm referring to 'Professional ASP.NET Design Patters' book application architecture. What are the workarounds if it needs user interaction between successive processing of the domain model entity and user gets ViewModels instead?

Comment: What pattern are you following?

Comment: I'm using DDD design. Domain model with services and business entities. Above that is MVP. Presenter contains necessary service and a view. Some business entities are quite complicated and there are views that needs to display some summary about the business entity. There is no need to pass entire entity to the view. I convert to e.g. MyEntity -> MyEntitySummaryView. I suppose that is some kind of MVP-VM pattern

Comment: So I think the answer is that there is no ViewModel in MVP. Make your MVP model your domain entity to solve the problem of passing the model back down the chain. Either that or you need to solve it within your presenter. You could always encapsulate the entity in another model if it helps make more sense to the view.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recommend separating the [presentation model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) from domain model either in terms of view model (in MVVM) or in terms of Model in MVC / MVP, because in medium to high domain complexity you design domain model in terms of business logic and object oriented design which has a granularity level other than presentation data, when you bind or present data you tend to show part of domain model and flatten some objects to be continent for presentation.

Another aspect is when developing distributed application sometimes you need to expose your data through services (remote facade) thus it is highly preferable to expose your objects in terms of DTOs not to expose you domain model because again the aspect of DTO is different in complexity and granularity than the domain model, dont force your domain model to be corrupted to be presentation friendly or consumer friendly, and dont corrupt your presentation model and consumers to use a business oriented domain model and increase the complexity of adopting them for presentation.

Comment: the model is separated as in the 'Professional ASP.NET Design Patters' but the question is how to handle the UI interaction while presenting DTOs to the User remains unanswered

Comment: You can think of interactions in two categories:
Read: which is just read only queries that returns DTOs to be presented to user.
Write: or better named Commands, which is write only commands that operate on domain entities and execute logic .. 

try to separate the concept of read from write, this is a variety of the CQRS architecture. check (http://moh-abed.com/2011/09/13/pure-old-ddd-with-a-twist-from-cqrs/)

Comment: Domain layer needs to pass ModelEntity to User for investigation. We can do that converting it to DTO. User then decide if to process that entity further in the domain layer. The problem is where to store ModelEntity to allow domain layer to process it further after user action if we use DTOs? What is the pattern to do that?

Comment: If it is all about action, you can instead of DTO create a Command object which holds the data needed for processing, then the application layer takes this command and execute it as actions on the domain model.

Comment: that does not solve the problem of passing a domain object to UI layer for user inspection in command body

Comment: not the domain object just put a dto which is a projection of the domain with data only with no business logic filled with only needed fields in command body